# cwac-camera: SingleShotMode: picture taken not being showed up on S3 and S4

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm using cwac-camera library to take pictures in my app.

I've written my own CameraHost class which overrides useSingleShotMode method so it returns true.

```
public boolean useSingleShotMode() {
    return true;
}
```

It works great on Samgung Galaxy Tab 2 but, although that S3 and S4 are listed as tested devices, I can't seem to make it freeze the preview after taking the picture. It keeps "updating" the preview window.

Is it possible to be a bug?
Does anybody knows if there's a workaround to solve this?

I'm using the international versions of S3 (GT-I9300) and S4 (GT-I9500)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

With the demo app, it takes two presses of the take-a-photo action bar item to actually trigger the single shot, on the S4 (and I presume the S3, though I have not tried that just yet). On the Galaxy Nexus, a single press of the take-a-photo action bar item suffices, which is the expected behavior.

I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/60) on this, and I will aim to fix this in my next development pulse on CWAC-Camera.

In terms of an end-user workaround, try tapping your trigger (e.g., action bar item) twice on those affected devices.

Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: tapping twice or waiting several seconds isn't solving this issue for me on a galaxy s5. I believe you mean tap twice on whatever calls takePicture(), correct?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: I mean the action bar item that looks like a still photo camera.

Comment: ah ok. is there a way to replicate this fix in my own cwac-camera app? Do I need to make an action bar item which calls takePicture() and tap that twice?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: No. The answer contains a link to [an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/60). If you read the issue, you will notice that I closed it, explaining that the problem really was that delivery of the image was slow, making it seem as though you either missed tapping the action bar item or otherwise did not get a picture.